# Get index in a for...of directive in Angular 2

Tags: angular

As of now, is there a way to get the current index of the iterable in a `for..of` directive in Angular 2? In others words, the equivalent of `$index` in Angular.js v1...

Example of code:

```html
<ul *for="#task of allTasks">
    <li>{{ $index}} - {{ task.label }}</li>
</ul>
```

(of course this code does not work, it does not provide the current index)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```html
<ul>
    <template ngFor let-task [ngForOf]="allTasks" let-i="index">
        <li>{{ i }} - {{ task.label }}</li>
    </template>
</ul>
```

But you have to use the very most recent version of the quickstart

BTW - the above is the equivalent of the following syntax sugar

```html
<li *ngFor="let task of allTasks; let i=index">{{ i }} - {{ task.label }}</li>
```

Comment: Actually, this does work in the quickstart as long as you have updated to the latest version of the quickstart

Comment: Thanks. The first version returns an error (I didn't updated the quickstart, I don't want to impact the rest of my code for now), but the second syntax works well. Thanks !

Answer (score 19):

The syntax has been updated and is now (as of Angular2.beta13, April 2016):

```html
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"></li>
```

For example:

```html
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
   item={{item}} index={{i}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use ***ngFor,let:**

```html
<li *ngFor="let menu of tempMenuModel.MenuItems.Items;let i=index" [ngClass]="{'active' : clickedItem == i}" (click)="SelectMenu(menu,i)">
      <span>{{menu.Header ==null?menu.Name:menu.Header}}</span>
</li>
```

**Component:**

```js
SelectMenu(menu, $index) {       
    this.clickedItem = $index;        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**update, use let, not #**

```html
<div *ngFor="let user of users; let i=index">
    {{i}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

<ng-container *ngFor=" let i of my-array; let index = index">

{{ index + 1}} - {{ i }}