# How to wrap elements inside ngFor loop?

Tags: angular, angular-template

Suppose I have a list of elements like the following

```ts
items = ['AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE','FFF'];
```

What I am trying to do is to wrap every 2 elements in an inner-wrap div tag.

Expected output:

```html
<div class="outer-wrap">
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <p>AAA</p>
    <p>BBB</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <p>CCC</p>
    <p>DDD</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <p>EEE</p>
    <p>FFF</p>
  </div>
</dvi>
```

Is this feasible in the `ngFor` loop?

Comment: You can get the `index` of the current item, it shows you how to do that in the docs. You could therefore do `<wrapper><thing></thing>` for even indices and `<thing></thing></wrapper>` for odd indices. But what if there is an odd length? Alternatively, pair up the items into another array and iterate over that. It would be helpful to actually try something, then you can be specific about the problem you're having (if you still are).

Comment: Here is how you can get the index https://stackoverflow.com/a/29336403/340760

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%` (modulo) in your template to split the array in `*ngFor`.

[Here is an working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k7qjle).

So you can do this in template:

```
<div class="outer-wrap">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of testArray; let i = index;">
    <div class="inner-wrap" *ngIf="(i+1) % 2 !== 1">
      <p>{{ testArray[i-1] }}</p>
      <p>{{ item }}</p>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Here is my `testArray`:

```
testArray: string[] = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE', 'FFF'];
```